# Is it possible to produce an XCFramework from a Swift Package with dependencies?

Tags: swift, xcodebuild, swift-package-manager, xcframework

I want to be able to take an internal SPM package, which depends on several other internal (and one external) SPM packages, and compile it into an XCFramework, using a series of `xcodebuild` like you would for a framework project.  For example, I have `PackageB`, which references `PackageA`, and I'm trying to build `PackageB.xcframework`.  The first step would be:

`xcodebuild -scheme PackageB -destination "generic/platform=iOS"  -configuration Release ARCHS="arm64" BUILD_DIR="./Build`

The tool's output indicates that the dependency packages are being resolved, but they are then not recognized by the compiler (i.e. code in `PackageB` which references `PackageA` will not compile because `PackageA` is unknown at that point).

Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: If your package has other swift packages as dependencies this will be difficult. It's something I'm researching myself at the moment.
I found the following blog post discussing it: https://kean.blog/post/xcframeworks-caveats.
Also, this post has some information about it as well: https://forums.swift.org/t/how-to-build-swift-package-as-xcframework/41414/4

Answer (score 5):

You can create xcframework from swift package by using [swift-create-xcframework](https://github.com/unsignedapps/swift-create-xcframework) command line tool, there is also GitHub action available for this.

If you don't want to use this tool, you can generate Xcode project by using `swift package generate-xcodeproj` command:

> OVERVIEW: Generates an Xcode project. This command will be deprecated soon.
>
>
> USAGE: swift package generate-xcodeproj 
>
>
> OPTIONS:
> --xcconfig-overrides 
> Path to xcconfig file
> --output        Path where the Xcode project should be generated
> --legacy-scheme-generator
> Use the legacy scheme generator
> --watch                 Watch for changes to the Package manifest to
> regenerate the Xcode project
> --skip-extra-files      Do not add file references for extra files to the
> generated Xcode project
> --version               Show the version.
> -h, -help, --help       Show help information.

and then [create xcframework with the generated Xcode project](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/distributing-binary-frameworks-as-swift-packages).

Comment: `swift package generate-xcodeproj` is not available